# How to switch Python version from 2.7 into 3.7 in unreal

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7, unreal-engine4

I change the `UE_PYTHON_DIR` to `"E:\python3.7Installer\python-3.7.7-amd64.exe"`

This is a python installer, and I rebuild the engine, but it is not working - my project is still using 2.7.

Hoping for an answer

Thanks

Comment: Use virtual environment built with python3.7

Comment: sorry,i  do not understand.how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself

it is a silly question

the UE_PYTHON_DIR should point to installed position

such as "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32"

and rebulid engine

rebuild myProject

solved